# How do I trigger a callback continuously while mouse is down in Rect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I have been trying to implement a simple functionality that is continuously triggered while the mouse is down on a button. I tried different solutions with different lifecycle methods of a component, unfortunately all of them fall into an endless loop.

My approach was to have a `while` loop that executes unless the button is not pressed anymore. The events which will update the component status to `isPressed: false` are `onMouseUp`, `onMouseLeave`. A quick sample:

```
...
componentWillUpdate() {
  while (this.state.isPressed) this.doSomething();
}

render() {
  <div
    onMouseDown={() => this.setState({ isPressed: true })}
    onMouseUp={() => this.setState({ isPressed: false })}
    onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ isPressed: false })}
  >
   Hey
  </div>
}
```

I understand why this approach does not work, but I have a hard time figuring out how to implement this the right way.

Comment: you could use a `setInterval`

Comment: Hi, Instead of using a single state for all events try to track the last mouse's event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/peoLeN

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       timer: 0
    }
    this.pressed = false;

    this.doIt = this.doIt.bind(this);
  }
  down() {
   if(!this.pressed)  //Prevent multimple loops!
     this.pressed = setInterval(this.doIt, 100 /*execute every 100ms*/);
  }
  up() {
    if(this.pressed) {  //Only stop if exists
     clearInterval(this.pressed);
     this.pressed = false;
     this.setState({timer: 0});
   }
  }
  doIt() {
    this.setState({timer: this.state.timer+1});
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <button
    onMouseDown={() => this.down()}
    onMouseUp={() => this.up()}
  >
   {this.state.timer}
  </button>
    </div>;
  }
}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to trigger something in an interval, so simply checking for the state is not an option (which possibly would be better, e.g. `this.state.isPressed ? doThis() : doThat()`). One approach you could chose is using Javascript's `setInterval`. Here's a simple example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.down = this.down.bind(this);
    this.up = this.up.bind(this);
    this.interval = {};
  }
  down() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.doSomething(), 100);
  }
  up() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  doSomething() {
    console.log('Did something!');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onMouseDown={this.down} onMouseUp={this.up} onMouseLeave={this.up}>
        Hey
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("View"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='View'></div>
```